# Validation closure not firing?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5

I want to create a custom validation using closures in Laravel 5.6 as explained in the docs:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/validation#using-closures

That is my code:

```
   public function store(Request $request)
    {
        \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'trainer' => [
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    return $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.');
                },
            ],
        ]);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
          dd($validator->messages());
        }

        dd('NO ERROR??');
   }
```

Testing it using

```
$this->post('/my_test_route', []);
```

Returns

> NO ERROR??

Why is this? If I change the code to

```
   public function store(Request $request)
   {
        Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'trainer' => 'required',
        ]);

        dd('NO ERROR??');
   }
```

I get as expected:

```
Illuminate\Support\MessageBag^ {#2408
  #messages: array:1 [
    "trainer" => array:1 [
      0 => "The trainer field is required."
    ]
  ]
  #format: ":message"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the problem. Because trainer was not given as an input, the custom validation method was not executed!

Adding `trainer` as parameter worked:

```
$this->post('/my_test_route', ['trainer' => 'test']);
```

Or as an alternative use:

```
'trainer' => [
               'required',
                function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
                    return $fail($attribute . ' is invalid.');
                },
            ],
```

Or, if you want to execute the validation method even if the parameter is not provided, and you don't want to make it required, then your custom rule should implement `Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ImplicitRule` (see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#implicit-rules)

Comment: Saved my day! Well noted in the docs @Adam.